# How to achieve overcompressed sound?

Tags: effects, compression, mastering, vst

How can I make a track sound like its over-compressed, like this one:

http://mp3.juno.co.uk/MP3/SF1228842-02-01-02.mp3

?

(I'm using the izotope Ozone plugin inside a VST host)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried simply pulling the threshold right down on the [Ozone Loudness Maximiser](http://www.izotope.com/products/audio/ozone/__maximizer.html)? See my [recent answer on loudness wars](http://audio.stackexchange.com/questions/1450/zoom-h2-recording-levels-are-too-low/1451#1451) though for why this might not be a good idea.

[image: Ozone Loudness Maximiser]